# Add DI for a Generic class in ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I want to register a generic class (this class is needed because I want to implement the patterns: Repository and Unit of work) in ConfigureServices in order to get dependency injection. But I do not know how.

Here my interface:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    void Add(TEntity obj);

    TEntity GetById(int id);

    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();

    void Update(TEntity obj);

    void Remove(TEntity obj);

    void Dispose();
}
```

Its implementation:

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable, IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    protected CeasaContext context;

    public BaseRepository(CeasaContext _context)            
    {
        context = _context;
    }
   /*other methods*/
}
```

And what I'm trying to do:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        var connection = @"Data Source=whatever;Initial Catalog=Ceasa;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

        services.AddDbContext<CeasaContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

        services.AddTransient<BaseRepository, IBaseRepository>();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50457230/2141621), regarding the use of UoW and Repository in ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework Core

Comment: I gonna read, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For open generics add services as follows

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IBaseRepository<>), typeof(BaseRepository<>));
```

Thus all dependencies on `IBaseRepository<TEntity>` will be resolved to `BaseRepository<TEntity>`

Answer (score -1):

But how is about this moment?

```cs
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<T,TK>), typeof(GenericRepository<T, TK>));
```

When we have as `T`, so `TK` here in these brackets `<>`
The compiler does not allow to do this in such syntax.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).